# How to use toFixed() method

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I would like to ask about the toFixed() method and its usage. I have a const called calories, which is a numeric data and I would like to round it to number with 2 decimal places.

```
const recipe = this.state.activeRecipe;
const calories = recipe.calories.toFixed(2);
console.log(calories);
```

I'm getting an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined`

Anyone knows how to fix this or if there is any method that I could use? Thank you!

The whole code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Recipe extends Component {
    state = {
        activeRecipe: []
    }
    componentDidMount = async() => {
        const title = this.props.location.state.recipe;
        const req = await fetch
        (`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${title}&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}`);

        const res = await req.json();
        this.setState({ activeRecipe: res.hits[0].recipe});
        console.log(this.state.activeRecipe);
        }
        render() {
            const recipe = this.state.activeRecipe;
            const calories = recipe.calories.toFixed(2);
            console.log(calories);
            return (
               <div className="container">
                       <h3 className="active-recipe">{recipe.label}</h3>
                       <div className="container">
                       {recipe.ingredients && recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient => {
                        return (
                            <p>{ingredient.text}</p>

                        );
                       })}
                       </div>
               </div>
            );
        }
}

export default Recipe;
```

Comment: just like the error says, you are trying to call a function property of an undefined object. your question has nothing to do with`toFixed`; instead, figure out why `recipe.calories` is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common problem. The first time `render` runs, `this.state.activeRecipe.calories` will be empty because the `fetch` call will not have returned yet. So you need to account for that in your `render` function by only calling `toFixed` if `this.state.activeRecipe.calories` exists:

```
const recipe = this.state.activeRecipe;
const calories = recipe.calories ? recipe.calories.toFixed(2) : null;
```

Note that you'll also need to adjust what is returned by the `render` function in this case, i.e. you need to know what to do if `this.state.activeRecipe` is empty.